# Where to get javapackager for JDK 13?

Tags: javafx

I use [JDK 13](https://jdk.java.net/13/). But it does not have `javapackager` (`javafxpackager`). Where should I get it?

For JDK 8 `javapackager` was in `jdk1.8.0_131\bin` folder.
Curently `jdk-13.0.1\bin` does not have `javapackager`.

Comment: Doesn't exist anymore. There is a replacement in the works, [JEP 343: Packaging Tool](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343), but it is experimental/early-access. You can get an early-access version [here](https://jdk.java.net/jpackage/).

Comment: Java SDK 14 now contains jpackage. Navigate to `path/to/JDK-14/bin`, and launch `jpackage --help` for more info. (On Windows, it would be `jpackage.exe --help`. Command may vary for other OSes.)

Comment: [jpackage Documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/preface.html#GUID-C8F52DC6-0750-497D-9DAB-2F88E10787BE)

Answer (score 1):

use jlink to make your java 13 runtime (with the arguments  `--strip-debug --no-header-files --no-man-pages --strip-native-commands` and if you wond add `--compress=2` save disk size) and than download the early jdk14 from [openjdk](https://jdk.java.net/14/) and use jpackage with `--runtime-image`

Comment: A tutorial of how to do that step by step can be found here: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX